# Godaddy subdomain not working

Tags: dns, subdomain, cpanel

I am having a hosting server and i want to create a subdomain for apis hosted on same server.What i want is suppose I have my domain name `domain.com` and want to have sub domain `api.domain.com` and set a folder path `/public_html/api` for it to load APIs.What I did is created a sub domain in `Domains/subdomains` section in cpanel and set folder path there and then created a CNAME pointing to IP of my server. but unfortunately when I open it, it gives me error **`Internal Server Error`**.

Please suggest what need to do for configurations ?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask on `webmasters` to get proper solution. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "Subdomain" option in cPanel and create your subdomain, pointing the root document to your desired folder `/public_html/api`

It might not update right away either. I just did this the other day, then I tried going to the new URL and it wasn't loading, I thought I did it wrong. I checked the subdomain the next day and it was working.

Comment: yeah the same thing is told by server support guy to me.if it worked i will mark your ans ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Wait for some specific time period, the domain will automatically be accessible after some time. actually, it needs some time to propagate and resolve IP associated with a particular sub-domain. it takes around 24-48 hours to resolve. To know more about this process, Please refer to the detailed explanation [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)